# Invalidate Timers when user press button home, doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have this code in app delegate that invokes an existing method in my view that invalidate timers and pause the music of my application:

**Appdelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{

    GameViewController *gamer = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
    [gamer EnterBackground];
}
```

**GameViewController.m**

```
-(void)EnterBackground{
    NSLog(@"App Enter in background mode!");

    [t1 invalidate];
    [t2 invalidate];
    [t3 invalidate];

    [_audioPlayer stop];
}
```

I can not understand why the simulator when I press the lock button or home, the NSLog works, but timers and the audio still continue to run, why this is happening? there is a possible solution?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the `GameViewController` and then invalidate the `NSTimer`s on this instance. I think you might want to use the active instance of `GameViewController` and call `EnterBackground ` on that instance. Also in Objective-c methods never start with a capitol. Also all `NSTimer` object are automatically invalidated when you app enters the background.

Comment: So that means there's no reason to worry right? this time when the app back from its inactive state to the active state automatically nstimers the return to work correct?

Comment: To my knowledge they **do not** become active after being invalidated.

Comment: If I delete this code up, and press button home, you say that the objetive-c automatically invalidated the nstimers correct? now if I go to my app again the nstimers continue running?

Comment: In this case I believe that NSTimers not invalidated, I believe that NSTimers go to stand by mode, right?

Comment: You will have to test that one yourself or read the documentation.